# htaccess physcially redirect in case of 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

To start off I know how to do a simple redirect to a `404` when a page doesn't exist with.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Is what I want to do is a physical redirect to the index page.  So if a user types in `mydomain.com/abc` and that page doesn't exist it does an actual redirect TO the index page.  I don't want the url to remain the same with the bad address.  Yes I know its not a big deal but it bugs me.  I could accomplish this by having a custom 404 page redirect to the homepage but I don't want this.

I've tried this with the `[R]` redirect flag and obviously it doesn't work.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,R]
```

**Update**

This is the error I get it rewrites the url to `mydomain.com/index.php`

I tried to remove the `index.php` with just `/` and it didn't redirect but gave the same error below.

```
The page isn't redirecting properly         

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
cookies.
```

Comment: What is happening? your rewriterules seem fine.

Comment: Do not update answers in the question. People wont bother to look down. For now I have remove the answer part.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Well you answer doesn't work exactly right.  Your answer allows `mydomain.com/rates.phpasfasfasdf`.  Which is why I posted what I did.

Comment: It will redirect `/rates.phpasfasfasdf` to `index.php` if it is not a valid file/directory. What  do you want to happen?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey I mistyped my comment `mydomain.com/rates.php/asfasf` does NOT redirect to `index.php`.

Comment: It will redirect! see the answer properly.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey you are talking about a whole different redirect then.  Which is not the question I asked.  `mydomain.com/test.php/asff` should physically redirect the user to `mydomain.com/` which your answer DOES NOT DO.  try it yourself.

Comment: It does do it! Read the answer properly. __see the 4 lines after `RewriteEngine on` `RewriteBase /` you have not used them!__

Comment: I mean these 4 lines: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+)$ [NC]` 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` 
`RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ $1.php`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8034/discussion-between-henesnarfel-and-thinkingmonkey)

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ $1.php 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R]
```

---

**Explanation:**

checks whether the file has extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+)$ [NC]
```

If not, checks whether file is present:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

If not a file, checks whether it is a folder which is present:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

If not append `.php`. If `/` is present at the end, remove it and append `.php`

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ $1.php
```

Checks whether the `.php` appended or whatever extension file is actually a file which is present:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

check whether it is a directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

If not, then it is a invalid file request and redirects it to `/`
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R]

Comment: works perfectly.  Didn't think I would have to redo the `RewriteCond` for the other rule.  I've added to my question exactly what I have that is working

Comment: Since this doesn't fully work from my end I'm going to reopen this.  If after a while no one is able to answer this I'll accept yours as an answer again.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your mod_rewrite based 404 handling:

```
# if it is not a file, directory or link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,R]
```

However I am not sure what are you doing in your first rule? Are you trying to add `.php` to each request URI?

Comment: no the first rule is to remove the `.php` extension from the url so they don't have to type `mydomain.com/test.php` they just type `mydomain.com/test`

Comment: Ok then keep that rule and append my rule in the end to get 404 redirection.

Comment: That will result in infinite loop **only if /index.php doesn't exist**. Please post matching entries from access.log and error.log in your question.

Comment: I'm hosting with godaddy and having some issues getting any log information.  I'll try and get it as soon as I can