# how set home page in case file missing(404 error page)

Tags: .htaccess

I want to display home page in case file missinng instead of file not found(404 error page). please let me know how can I do by the use of htaccess file.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380591/htaccess-physcially-redirect-in-case-of-404) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ErrorDocument 404 www.yourdomain.com

or /index.html (or the home page of your website).

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess file insert

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/badrequest.html

Point the /errors/badrequest.html to your home page.